# How to fill textareas and select option (select tag) and hit submit (input tag) via python?

Tags: python, form-submit

I work with python and data mine some content which I categorize into different categories.

Then I go to a specific webpage and submit manually the results.

Is there a way to automate the process? I guess this is a "form-submit" thread but I haven't seen any relevant module in Python. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: On the webpage, the form is probably submitted via http request. You could try to automate the same kind of request with the `httplib` module

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver is the most popular way to drive web pages, but Python also has beautifulsoup;  Either library will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want make this automatic yo have to see which params are send in the form and make a request with this params to the endpoint but directly from your python app, or search a package that simulate a browser and fill the form, but I think that the correct way is making the request directly from your app